# Gatsby with strapi data fetch realtime issue in development

Tags: graphql, gatsby, strapi

I am using Gatsby with strapi , whenever I update/create some fields in strapi, I am not able to get the data when I reload gatsby in development. Whenever I restart Gatsby using Gatsby develop, it will fetch the new data. Does this mean that whenever I change a field or content in Strapi, Gatsby has to be restarted? What is the recommended workflow for development since restarting every time will slow down the process.

my Gatsby-config.js is:

```
/**
 * Configure your Gatsby site with this file.
 *
 * See: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-config/
 */

/**
 * @type {import('gatsby').GatsbyConfig}
 */
require("dotenv").config({
  path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
});

const strapiConfig = {
  apiURL: process.env.STRAPI_URL,
  accessToken: process.env.STRAPI_TOKEN,
  collectionTypes: [
    { singularName: "page", queryParams: { populate: "deep" } },
    { singularName: "platform-card", queryParams: { populate: "deep" } },
  ],
  singleTypes: ["footer-section"],
  watchContent: true,
};
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `Gatsby Default Starter`,
    description: `Kick off your next, great Gatsby project with this default starter. This barebones starter ships with the main Gatsby configuration files you might need.`,
    author: `@gatsbyjs`,
    siteUrl: `https://gatsbystarterdefaultsource.gatsbyjs.io/`,
  },
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-image`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `gatsby-starter-default`,
        short_name: `starter`,
        start_url: `/`,
        background_color: `#663399`,
        // This will impact how browsers show your PWA/website
        // https://css-tricks.com/meta-theme-color-and-trickery/
        // theme_color: `#663399`,
        display: `minimal-ui`,
        icon: `src/images/gatsby-icon.png`, // Thiter¸s path is relative to the root of the site.
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-source-strapi",
      options: strapiConfig,
    },
  ],
};
```

Example: My data fetching queuing in home page is:

```
const homeData = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query MyQuery {
      allStrapiPage(filter: { slug: { eq: "home" } }) {
        edges {
          node {
            Title
            slug
            internal {
              content
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Thank you!